# Windows 10 not showing login screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, login

Windows is only showing lock screen, the login screen is not displaying.

After making few changes in msconfig windows is not showing login screen. Fortunately I remember what I changed:

- changed to 4 processor from drop down
- changed to normal startup
- no GUI boot is checked

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish by making these changes in msconfig? If you can see the Restart button, hold the SHIFT key on your keyboard and then click it to restart the computer into Troubleshooting Mode, which will allow you to run the automated repair tools.